# How do I resolve "Cannot find connection in scope" error (SQLite)?

Tags: swift, cocoapods, sqlite.swift

I'm trying to use sqlite.swift in a small app I'm developing, but I'm new to Swift and SQLite. I used CocoaPods to install sqlite.swift. I used these commands:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup --verbose
```

I then navigated to the directory for my app and entered:

```
pod init
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

I then edited the pod as follows:

```rb
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'GeneralPractice (iOS)' do
    pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.13.1'
end
```

I then open the app workspace and add import `sqlite3` to `ContentView.swift`, and then add this code before `struct ContentView: View {`:

```swift
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true
).first!

let db = try Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
```

When I run the app, I get this error:

> "Cannot find 'Connection' in scope"

Given how new I am to this and to Swift, I suspect I'm making some simple error, but any help resolving this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you imported the library, `import SQLite` In ContentView.swift?

Comment: There is a `pod init`, but is there a `pod install`? Do you see `SQLite.swift` in your workspace, in the Pods folder?

Comment: My ContentView file has import sqlite3, not sqlite. When I tried to enter sqlite manually, I got an error. The Pods folder does have SQLite.swift in several lines. It does not appear as one of the apps Frameworks.

Comment: According to the docs on https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift, you need to `import SQLite`. The module itself imports sqlite3 under the hood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. As Kiril S. suggested, SQLite.swift only works if "import SQLite" is used. However, as far as I can tell, "import SQLite" can only be used without errors in a file that contains no Views. When I use "import SQLite" in a file with any View (like ContentView.swift) I get multiple error messages. If I create a new Swift file without any View, everything works fine.